# Creating a table with proportional values

Tags: r

I have got a data set that looks like this:

```
COMPANY       DATABREACH        CYBERBACKGROUND
A             1                 2
B             0                 2 
C             0                 1
D             0                 2 
E             1                 1
F             1                 2
G             0                 2  
H             0                 2
I             0                 2
J             0                 2
```

No I want to create the following: 40% of the cases that the column DATABREACH has the value of 1, I want the value CYBERBACKGROUND to take the value of 2. I figure there must be some function to do this, but I cannot find it.

Comment: If I understand, then whenever `DATABREACH` has a value of 1, you want to randomly overwrite (prob of 0.4) `CYBERBACKGROUND` with a value of 2, is that right? Do you realize then that only company "E" has the chance of changing here, all others will remain unchanged?

Comment: This is just a part of the dataset, I have like 11,000 observations. But yes, whenever DATABREACH has a value of 1, I want to randomly overwrite (prob of 0.4) CYBERBACKGROUND with a value of 2.

Answer (score 0):

```r
ind <- which(df$DATABREACH == 1)
ind <- ind[rbinom(length(ind), 1, prob = 0.4) > 0]
df$CYBERBACKGROUND[ind] <- 2
```

The above is a bit more efficient in that it only pulls randomness for as many as strictly required. If you aren't concerned (11000 doesn't seem too high), you can reduce that to

```r
df$CYBERBACKGROUND <-
  ifelse(df$DATABREACH == 1 & rbinom(nrow(df), 1, prob = 0.4) > 0,
         2, df$CYBERBACKGROUND)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(CYBERBACKGROUND = replace(CYBERBACKGROUND,
    sample(which(DATABREACH == 0), sum(ceiling(sum(DATABREACH) * 0.4))), 2))
```